# Angularjs' routes and best practices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm new to angular js and having some troubles make my first project works. Here is the github of my project :
https://github.com/User199011/ClientCrossPlateform

I'm also using node.js with node-webkit.

When I launch my application I have this error :

```
includes\routes\routes.js:10
                templateUrl : '../includes/files/home/home.html',
                ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:69:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:472:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:354:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
```

I've tried several syntaxes (using "/" before, without, etc) without success.

I thought maybe you could help me with this ?

Second question about best pratices. I've read some articles about architecture in Angular but they were not really answering my questions.

Now I just want a simple application where an un logged user can just connect itself, and a logged user can access to the content. So was thinking of these modules for my application, correct me if there are better answers please (I'm more used to models under C#/C++/java) :
- module loggedContent (dependencies : modules about the logged possibilies  : messages, settings ...)
- module unlogged
- module application (dependencies : loggedContent, unlogged)

This way I was able to add as many content as I want without touching the application, Is this a good understanding of angular/js architecture ?

But as the services in angular/js seems to be injected in a module (I want some of the services to be accessible to all modules, example "getCurrentUser") I was not able to find how my "loggedContent" module could have access to the services defined in my application.

Comment: The syntax error is almost definitely because you are missing a comma on the line above it.

Comment: And the comma is not necessary on that templateUrl line as it is the last property!  Looks like a copy and paste issue.

Comment: Waow... I spent hours browsing google to find my error... Thank you.